# ajax form alert (jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, joomla

I have a problem with ajaxform. 
I have a php file called captcha.php that it generates a captcha:

```
<?php
session_start();

$random_number =  rand(1,9).rand(1,9).rand(1,9).rand(1,9).rand(1,9).rand(1,9);
$_SESSION['captcha_text'] = $random_number;

$captcha_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("captcha.jpg");
$font_color = imagecolorallocate($captcha_image, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($captcha_image, 5, 20, 5, $random_number, $font_color);
imagejpeg($captcha_image);
imagedestroy($captcha_image);
?>
```

I have another php file called pro.php that it is executed on action form and send an e-mail with form's data:

```
<?php
session_start();
@extract($_POST);
$sub = "Curriculum di: ".stripslashes($name);
$message = stripslashes($messaggio);
$fromail = stripslashes($email);
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 
$headers = "From: ".$fromail;
$headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";
$message="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"
--_2_$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
$message
--_2_$boundary--
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 
$attachment
--_1_$boundary--";
if(isset($_POST['txtCaptcha']) and $_POST['txtCaptcha'] !='')
   if($_SESSION['captcha_text'] == $_POST['txtCaptcha'])
       mail('myemail@myemail.it', $sub, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Now I would like to show an alert if the email was sent correctly or not:

```
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#myFormId').ajaxForm(function() {
          //Instructions to enter
    }); 
  }); 
</script>
```

What's the solution? (Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: First: if(isset($_POST['txtCaptcha']) and $_POST['txtCaptcha'] !='')
   if($_SESSION['captcha_text'] == $_POST['txtCaptcha'])
       echo mail('myemail@myemail.it', $sub, $message, $headers);
?>

Comment: Then use $.ajax from jquery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call success param:

```
$("your-form").ajaxForm({
    success: function(res, status, xhr, form) {
        // ... call the alert
    }
});
```

Good coding.

Comment: But in my case the form is sent whether the captcha is correct or not; the captcha check is done within the pro.php file, so with your code the alert will not always be activated? Because the form is always sent.

Comment: If you ECHO the mail() func. The ajax will recibe in **res** with the mail() value. (1 if sended) so.. just ask if res is == 1 then the mail was sent, 0 if the email was not sended